# Ingress-NGINX - Set host header dynamically depending on path

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-ingress

I use [Ingress-nginx](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx) and I need to rewrite the `Host` header sent to the proxied Kubernetes Service based on the `path` of the original request. This must happen based on some variable or regular expression. I cannot hard code paths because this **needs to work for any path** automatically.

Basically I need something like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  namespace: my-ns
annotations:
    # below what's commented out almost works but adds a leading "/" to header
    # nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/upstream-vhost: $request_uri.example.com
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/upstream-vhost: $PATH.example.com
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: 'example.com'
      http:
        paths:
        - backend:
            service:
              name: my-svc
              port:
                number: 80
          path: /$PATH
          pathType: Prefix
```

I wonder if this is somehow possible to implement with annotation `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet` or `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet` but I don't understand these annotations well enough. I've tried out these annotations by passing in a `location` and also attempted to use `map` module with no luck so far.

Context: This reverse proxy is set up in front of Knative and Knative's routing works through `Host` header.

Comment: I was able to figure out a hacky solution for this but would still highly appreciate if someone would be able to figure this out without using any `snippet` annotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> without any `snippet` annotation

Then... considering [NGINX Ingress annotation snippets contain LUA code execution](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/rootfs/etc/nginx/lua/plugins/README.md) (which can be [a security issue](https://docs.bridgecrew.io/docs/prevent-nginx-ingress-annotation-snippets-which-contain-lua-code-execution), by the way), you might consider using [Lua](https://www.lua.org/) through a [custom Lua plugin](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/rootfs/etc/nginx/lua/plugins/README.md).

A simple Lua script would be enough to capture the first segment of the request path and sets it as the `Host` header suffixed with `.example.com`.

Create a `dynamic-host-header/main.lua`: (inspired from [the official example](https://github.com/ElvinEfendi/ingress-nginx-openidc/blob/master/rootfs/etc/nginx/lua/plugins/openidc/main.lua))

```lua
local _M = {}

function _M.rewrite()
    -- Check if this is the default backend, if so, skip processing.
    if ngx.var.proxy_upstream_name == "upstream-default-backend" then
        return
    end

    local path = ngx.var.uri
    local captured_path = string.match(path, "^/([^/]+)")
    if captured_path then
        ngx.req.set_header("Host", captured_path .. ".example.com")
    end
end

return _M
```

Before building a custom `ingress-nginx` image, you can start with testing that plugin into the `ingress-nginx` pod:

Create a ConfigMap with the content of your plugin:

```bash
kubectl create configmap dynamic-host-header-plugin --from-file=dynamic-host-header/main.lua -n <NAMESPACE_WHERE_INGRESS_IS_RUNNING>
```

And modify the `ingress-nginx` deployment to mount this ConfigMap to `/etc/nginx/lua/plugins/dynamic-host-header` (as mentioned in [the "installing plugin" section](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/rootfs/etc/nginx/lua/plugins/README.md#installing-a-plugin)):

```bash
kubectl edit deployment -n <NAMESPACE_WHERE_INGRESS_IS_RUNNING> nginx-ingress-controller
```

Add the volume and `volumeMounts` as follows:

```yaml
...
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx-ingress-controller
    ...
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /etc/nginx/lua/plugins/dynamic-host-header
      name: dynamic-host-header
    ...
  volumes:
  - name: dynamic-host-header
    configMap:
      name: dynamic-host-header-plugin
```

Now, you need to enable the plugin by updating the `nginx-ingress-controller`'s ConfigMap:

Edit the ConfigMap:

```bash
kubectl edit configmap nginx-configuration -n <NAMESPACE_WHERE_INGRESS_IS_RUNNING>
```

Add (or update) the `plugins` configuration setting:

```yaml
data:
  plugins: "dynamic-host-header"
```

Finally, restart the ingress-nginx pods to pick up the changes:

```bash
kubectl rollout restart deployment/nginx-ingress-controller -n <NAMESPACE_WHERE_INGRESS_IS_RUNNING>
```

With this Lua plugin enabled, the `Host` header should be dynamically set based on the request path, as required.

---

Note: the [OP nichoio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6312338/nichoio) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76835282/ingress-nginx-set-host-header-dynamically-depending-on-path/76845902?noredirect=1#comment135618666_76845902):

> Turns out it I can't get it to work yet.
> Using `ngx.req.set_header()`, I can add new headers and alter most existing headers (e.g. `user-agent`). Host however won't change.
> I'm debugging this with an Ingress pointing to a svc/pod running `mendhak/http-https-echo`.

The behavior you have observed is because the `Host` header in Nginx is a bit special. When you change it with [`ngx.req.set_header()`](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxreqset_header), it does not necessarily reflect in the request sent to the upstream server. The value that gets sent as the `Host` header to the upstream is defined by the [`proxy_set_header Host` directive](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/#passing-request-headers).

However, there is a workaround using Lua.

Instead of setting the `Host` header directly in the Lua script, you can assign the new `Host` value to a variable.

```lua
local _M = {}

function _M.rewrite()
    -- Check if this is the default backend, if so, skip processing.
    if ngx.var.proxy_upstream_name == "upstream-default-backend" then
        return
    end

    local path = ngx.var.uri
    local captured_path = string.match(path, "^/([^/]+)")
    if captured_path then
        ngx.var.dynamic_host_header = captured_path .. ".example.com"
    end
end

return _M
```

Here, instead of `ngx.req.set_header("Host", ...)`, a custom variable `ngx.var.dynamic_host_header` is assigned the desired value.

Then, you can use this variable in a custom `proxy_set_header` directive.

Use the `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet` annotation: Add this to your Ingress resource. That lets you set the custom proxy header.

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  namespace: my-ns
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      proxy_set_header Host $dynamic_host_header;
```

The `proxy_set_header` directive in the annotation makes sure that the desired `Host` header is sent to the upstream server.

---

The [OP nichoio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6312338/nichoio), however, confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76835282/ingress-nginx-set-host-header-dynamically-depending-on-path/76845902#comment135732838_76845902) that:

> Unfortunately, `configuration-snippet` also didn't work.
> [IIRC](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/IIRC), the `$dynamic_host_header` var is not available inside the snippet when following the alternative solution.
>
> Workaround for now is to create one Ingress resource per path/header.

Another approach you might consider is to use a service mesh like [Istio](https://istio.io/) to manage headers and routing rules more flexibly. Istio provides more fine-grained control over HTTP headers, including the Host header.
While introducing a service mesh adds complexity, it might give you the control you need for this specific scenario.

In an Istio-based approach, you could leverage [Istio's `VirtualService`](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/) to specify the routing rules and header manipulation logic. Specifically, you can use the [`headers` field in the HTTP route](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/#HTTPRoute) to rewrite the `Host` header based on the request path.

For instance:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: my-virtualservice
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - my-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: "/path1"
    route:
    - destination:
        host: path1-service.default.svc.cluster.local
      headers:
        request:
          set:
            Host: "path1.example.com"
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: "/path2"
    route:
    - destination:
        host: path2-service.default.svc.cluster.local
      headers:
        request:
          set:
            Host: "path2.example.com"
  # additional path-based rules
```

- The `VirtualService` applies to all incoming requests (`hosts: ["*"]`) on a specific Istio gateway (`my-gateway`).
- Two HTTP routes are defined; each matches a URI prefix (`/path1` and `/path2`).
- For each HTTP route, the `destination` specifies which Kubernetes service to route to.
- The `headers` field allows you to manipulate headers. In this case, the `Host` header is rewritten based on the matching path.

This works with an Istio Gateway named `my-gateway` that is configured to handle the incoming traffic. You would also need to replace `path1-service.default.svc.cluster.local` and `path2-service.default.svc.cluster.local` with the actual service names you are using in your cluster.

That approach provides a way to conditionally rewrite the `Host` header based on the request path, and it could scale as you can define any number of such path-based rules in the `VirtualService` specification.

Comment: turns out it I can't get it to work yet. Using `ngx.req.set_header()` I can add new headers and alter most existing headers (e.g. user-agent). host however won't change. I'm debugging this with an Ingress pointing to  a svc/pod running `mendhak/http-https-echo`. Will keep investigating this.

Comment: @nichoio OK, let me know what you find. I have included a caveat (your comment) in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @nichoio I have edited the answer to address your comment and proposed a workaround.

Comment: Unfortunately, `configuration-snippet` also didn't work. iirc, the `$dynamic_host_header` var is not available inside the snippet when following the alternative solution. Workaround for now is to create one `Ingress` resource per path/header. I might revisit this problem in the future.

Comment: @nichoio Creating separate Ingress resources for each path/header is a pragmatic workaround, albeit it may not scale well if you have a large number of different paths and host headers to deal with.

Another approach you might consider is to use a service mesh like Istio to manage headers and routing rules more flexibly. Istio provides more fine-grained control over HTTP headers, including the `Host` header. While introducing a service mesh adds complexity, it might give you the control you need for this specific scenario.

Comment: @nichoio I have edited the answer with an illustration of what that alternative approach would look like.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, setting the `Host` header depending on the `path` can be achieved like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  namespace: my-ns
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      location ~* "^/(?<myvar>.+)$" {
        proxy_set_header        Host $myvar.example.com;
        proxy_pass              http://my-svc.my-ns.svc.cluster.local;        
        proxy_http_version      1.1;
      }
spec:
  rules:
    - host: "example.com"
      http:
        paths:
        - backend:
            service:
              name: thisisignored
              port:
                number: 80
          path: /
          pathType: Prefix
```

So we need `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet` and also it must be added `proxy_http_version 1.1;`, otherwise it won't work.

Note that apparently `server-snippet` overrules what is defined as `service` in the specs - the value of `backend.service.name` is ignored. So be careful when using `server-snippet` annotation as it may break the Ingress configuration is some way.

Comment: I will accept the first answer that can solve this without any `snippet` annotation.